# How to start math formulae in new line if bad boxed in latex?

Tags: latex

What sort of code should I put in preamble, such that every math fomula (in dolar signs) that is too long to fit in line width (a.k.a. produces Bad Box) start in new line (like putting // before equation) ? Or is it impossible to detect and prevent Bad Box in compiling ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `\sloppy` or `\sloppypar`, but that will reduce the quality of the line breaks.

Take a look [here](http://www.tex.ac.uk/cgi-bin/texfaq2html?label=overfull).

Answer (score 0):

Are you talking about inline math or TeX-style $$? In the first case: think about putting it in its own environment, long inline math isn't a good idea. In the second case, start using `align` (or the appropriate environment) and place those breaks yourself. Or use `breqn`, it will do it automatically.

In case it's inline and you want it to stay inline: consider rewriting your sentences, as usual with bad boxes. And consider using `microtype` if you're building to pdf, it will enhance the flexibility of the fonts, hence, more possibilities for line breaking.

I don't have an actual solution for line breaks in inline math, I usually resort to these tricks. Maybe someone with a better insignt in inline math can help you with that :).